# Separate class template declaration and specialization

Tags: c++, templates, linker, dllexport

I have a declaration of class template. Assume that specializations of this template save and load an object from a data base with a specific string id. I need to use this template only for specific types and I placed these specializations into different cpp-files.

```
// TemplateInterface.h
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static void save(T const& v);
    static T load();
};
```

Let's assume, that I use this code for saving values of std::tuple.

```
// TemplateInterface.cpp
template <>
struct __declspec(dllexport) Foo<Class1>
{
    static void save(Class1 const& v)
    {
        MyDatabase::save("class1-id", v);
    }
    static Class1 load()
    {
        return MyDatabase::load("class1-id");
    }
};

template <>
struct __declspec(dllexport) Foo<Class2>
{
    static void save(Class2 const& v)
    {
        MyDatabase::save("class2-id", v);
    }
    static Class2 load()
    {
        return MyDatabase::load("class2-id");
    }
};
```

As you can see, the only difference is string ids. (Without __declspec(dllexport) this code doesn't work.)
I figured out, that I can do like this in a **single** file:

```
// Source.cpp
template <typename T, typename Traits>
struct Helper
{
    static void save(T const& v)
    {
        MyDatabase::save(Traits::getID(), v);
    }
    static T load()
    {
        return MyDatabase::load(Traits::getID());
    }
};


template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static void save(T const& v);
    static T load();
};

struct Class1Traits 
{
    static std::string getID() { return "class1-id"; }
};

struct Class2Traits
{
    static std::string getID() { return "class2-id"; }
};

template<>
struct Foo<Class1> : Helper<Class1, Class1Traits> {};

template<>
struct Foo<Class2> : Helper<Class2, Class2Traits> {};
```

But when I do it in different files (declaration in TemplateInterface.h and specialization in TemplateInterface.cpp), i get linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static Class1__cdecl Foo<Class1>::load()" referenced in function _main
```

Same error for the other methods.
Adding dllexport and using doesn't help.
Could you help me?

The only solution I know is to explicitly invoke base class methods from the template specizlization. But this is a strange solution.

Answer (score -1):

Template instantiation is not the same as a template specialization.

For instance, take this code, and tell me what happens:

```
// TemplateInterface.h
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static T load();
};

int main() {
    int foo = Foo<int>::load();
}
```

Then, add this in a separated, compiled cpp:

```
template <>
struct Foo<int>
{
    static int load_special()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

As you can see, according to the specialization, there is no `Foo<int>::load()`, but only `Foo<int>::load_special()`.

Your code has in fact an ODR violation.

If you desire to specialize your template and want to hide the specialization into it's own cpp file, you must tell the compiler that there is specializations for your type to prevent it from instantiating the primary template.

This is done by forward declaring your specializations:

```
template<>
struct Foo<int>; // specialization elsewhere!
```

Comment: And where I shold put this forward declaration?

Comment: In your header, to tell any compiler that includes it that there's a specialization somewhere